# adding Variables of different types in C

Tags: c, floating-point, long-integer, short

float + (short)long = ?

I am adding these types and based on my calculation I am getting a float as an answer but the right answer is double.
can anyone give me an example of how it becomes double or explanation..

Comment: When adding a `float` to an integral type, the result is `float`. If you want `double` you have to start with `double` specifically.

Comment: What do you mean by `(short)long`? And what do you mean by "the right answer is double"? What's more "right" about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators that take two arithmetic operands in C always require both operands to be of the same type. If they aren't, then one or both are converted according to the *usual arithmetic conversions*, which are fully described in section 6.3.1.8 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the link is to a draft of the 2011 standard).

Briefly:

- If either operand is of type `long double`, the other is converted to `long double`.
- Otherwise, if either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double.
- Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`.

This is followed by a set of rules for two operands of integer type, which don't apply in this case.

If you need a `double` result, you need to convert one or both operands to `double`. If you convert just one of them, it will cause the other to be converted as well. (You might want to convert both just to be explicit.)

For example, if you have:

```
float f;
long n;
double x = f + n;
```

then the result of the addition is `float`, which is converted to `double` only after the addition is performed. To do a `double` multiplication, change the last line to:

```
double x = (double)f + (double)n;
```

On the other hand, if you want a `double` result, it's very likely that your `float` operand should have been declared as a `double` in the first place. `double` is in some sense the "default" floating-point type in C (it's the type of unsuffixed literals like `1.0`, for example). `float` is used mostly when it's important to save memory space, such as when you have very large arrays. On many systems, `float` arithmetic isn't even any faster than `double` arithmetic (though I'm not 100% sure on that last point).

Answer (score -1):

try to do:

```
float F;
short L;
double res = (double)(F + L);
```

Comment: No, the addition is still done in type `float` and converted to `double` only after the addition has been done. The cast does nothing, since it would have been converted to `double` anyway. To do a `double` addition, you need to convert one or both of the operands. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22394005/827263).